# How to calculate expected value of integral?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, levy-processes

How to calculate 
$E \big[(\int ^{t} _{-\infty} e^{\lambda u} d\tilde{L_\alpha}(u))^A (\int ^{t+h} _{-\infty} e^{\lambda u} d\tilde{L_\alpha}(u))^B\big]$,
where
\begin{align}
\tilde{L}_\alpha (t) = \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
L_\alpha(t),\quad t\geq 0 \\
L_\alpha(-t),\quad \text{otherwise}
\end{array} \right.
\end{align}
and a $\{L(t),t\geq0\}$ is $\alpha$-stable Levy motion, thus $L(0)=0$ a.s., has stationary increments and $L(t)-L(s)\sim S_{\alpha}((t-s)^{\frac{1}{\alpha}},\beta,0)$ for any $0\leq s\leq t\leq \infty$ and for some $0<\alpha\leq 2$, $-1\leq\beta\leq1$.

I have to calculate fractional lower order covariance, thus I have
\begin{align}
FLOC(X(t),X(t+h),A,B)=E \big[\big(\int ^{t} _{-\infty} e^{-\lambda (t-u)} d\tilde{L_\alpha}(u)\big)^A \big(\int ^{t+h} _{-\infty} e^{-\lambda (t+h-u)} d\tilde{L_\alpha}(u)\big)^B\big]=e^{-\lambda t A}e^{-\lambda (t+h) B} E \big[\big(\int ^{t} _{-\infty} e^{\lambda u} d\tilde{L_\alpha}(u)\big)^A \big(\int ^{t+h} _{-\infty} e^{\lambda u} d\tilde{L_\alpha}(u)\big)^B\big],
\end{align}
with the parameters $A, B\geq 0$ satifying $A+B <\alpha$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I'd like to be able to help, but I'm not able to pick out details that I'd need to *calculate* the expected value of such integrals.  You mention the dependence of integrals on a [Lévy process (motion)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_process), but the capitalized variables $A,B$ deserve more of an explanation.  It is customary to use capitalized variables for *random variables*, but I don't think that is the intention here in that you've pulled factors depending on $A,B$ outside the expected value operator.

Comment: A and B are not random variables. They are just parameters, such that $A,B\geq 0$ and $A+B< \alpha$.